# Converting string to binary and back again does not give the same string

Tags: java, encryption

I'm writing a Simplified DES algorithm to encrypt and subsequently decrypt a string. Suppose I have the initial character `(` which has the binary value `00101000` which I get using the following algorithm:

```
public void getBinary() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] plaintextBinary = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    for(byte b : plaintextBinary){
        int val = b;
        int[] tempBinRep = new int[8];
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            tempBinRep[i] = (val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
            val <<= 1;
        }

        binaryRepresentations.add(tempBinRep);
    }
}
```

After I perform the various permutations and shifts, `(` and it's binary equivalent is transformed into `10001010` and it's ASCII equivalent `Š`. When I come around to decryption I pass the same character through the `getBinary()` method I now get the binary string `11000010` **and** *another* binary string `10001010` which translates into ASCII as `x(`.

Where is this rogue `x` coming from?

Edit: The full class can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/edda3ed7ea4cc9a45b75).

Comment: Š isn't a character in ASCII. I would *strongly* urge you not to encode arbitrary binary data as text using a regular encoding (which would assume that you've really got text). Instead, use base64...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't supplied the decrypting code, so we can't know for sure, but I would guess you missed the encoding either when populating your String.  Java [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are encoded in UTF-16 by default.  Since you're forcing UTF-8 when encrypting, I'm assuming you're doing the same when decrypting.  The problem is, when you convert your encrypted bytes to a String for storage, if you let it default to UTF-16, you're probably ending up with a two-byte character because the 10001010 is 138, which is beyond the 127 range for ASCII charaters that get represented with a single byte.

So the "x" you're getting is the byte for the code page, followed by the actual character's byte.  As suggested in the comments, you'd do better to just store the encrypted bytes as bytes, and not convert them to Strings until they're decrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll take a look into that. I've added the full class to the OP too.